# How to show that this set is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How to show that this set is connected?

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x & -y\\ y & x\end{bmatrix};x^2+y^2=1,x,y\in \mathbb R\right\}.$$

I tried to show it using path-connectedness which failed.How should I prove connectedness? Please help.

Comment: The $x$ and $y$ values form a circle, so this is an image of a circle (and the image of a connected set is connected).

Comment: Can you define a continuous path between two of these matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Re-write it $S:=\Big\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\mid\theta\in\mathbb{R}\Big\}$ and show that $S$ is path-connected showing that the path
$$f:[\theta_1,\theta_2]\to S, \,f(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$ is well-defined and continuous.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @Micheal Burr;

I think that this  would work:

Let $A$ be the given set

Define $f:S^1 \to A $ by $f(x+iy)=$ \begin{bmatrix} x & -y \\y & x\end{bmatrix}.

Obviously this is a surjective map and continuous image of a connected set being connected so will be $A$